# which package contains EnableKinesisStreamingDestinationRequest

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-kinesis

Please help me find which package or package version I need in order to call `EnableKinesisStreamingDestinationRequest` to enable Kinesis streaming on a dynamoDB table.

The Amazon docs point to this package:`com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model`
But I can't get past the error in eclipse saying:

```
com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.EnableKinesisStreamingDestinationRequest cannot be resolved
```

Eclipse help took me to the class `EnableKinesisStreamingDestinationRequest` and it shows a different package at the top:

```
package software.amazon.awssdk.services.dynamodb.model;
```

But import `software.amazon.awssdk.services.dynamodb.model.EnableKinesisStreamingDestinationRequest` cannot be resolved either.

Thanks in advance.